# Need to catch the proper error for SMTP send email code

Tags: c#, smtp

For some reason my program does not send email using SMTP server, it stops somewhere in this code, and I can't debug it, because it happens with the compiled .exe

```
public static void sendLog(MailMessage mail) {
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress(Constants.EMAIL_SENDER);
    mail.To.Add(Constants.EMAIL_RECEIVER);
    mail.Subject = Environment.UserName;
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Constants.EMAIL_SENDER, Constants.EMAIL_SENDER_PASSWORD);
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

what I need is to know what try/catch to use, and to handle the proper Exception to write in a .txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use proper **SMTP Exception**

```
  catch (SmtpException ex)
   {    
     // write to log file

    string msg = "Failure sending email"+ex.Message+" "+ex.StackTrace;

   }
```